# General Linear Model: using categorical data to explain a continuous variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, python, image-processing

I'm trying to model Mean Opinion Scores (MOS) about image quality, based on an image data base. The data base has 3000 images, it has 25 original images, 24 distortions of each one and 5 levels of distortion for each distortion type (25*24*5 = 3000). The MOS is a real number between 0 and 9.

The MOS distribution doesn't seem to be normal since according to its histogram it is not symmetric. 
[image]

I think a Beta distribution would be fine. Do you agree with me? What other distribution could be used?

What confuses me is that the explanatory variables are categorical,

Image: it is a number in the range 1, 2, ... up to 25

Distortion: it is a number in the range 1, 2, ... up to 24

Level: it is a number in the range 1, 2, ... up to 5

I'm not sure how to work with categorical variables in a General Linear Model.

I don't know what link function use and why neither.

I wrote this code in python to fit the model:

```
# the data were previously loaded in a numpy array called data_array

X = np.empty((3000, 3))

X[:,0] = data_array[:, 0].astype(int) # image
X[:,1] = data_array[:, 1].astype(int) # distortion
X[:,2] = data_array[:, 2].astype(int) # level

mos = data_array[:, 3] # mos

X = sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False) # it appends a column of 1's

model = sm.GLM(mos, X, family=sm.families.Gamma())

results = model.fit()

print(results.summary())
```

I used a Gamma distribution because, Beta distribution is not available in python... do you know how to get a Beta distribution from another distribution?... or maybe I should try with R not Python...

Any kind of help is welcome.

Thanks you very much!

Best regards

Lucy

Comment: If you're fitting a model with predictors (IVs) then the appearance of the marginal distribution of the response (DV) is (largely) irrelevant  -- it's a mixture of the various conditional distributions, and it's the *conditional* distribution that the model describes / that the assumptions relate to. Many posts on site discuss this issue. It's usually not possible to make an assessment about the suitability of an assumed conditional distribution without actually having fitted a suitable model for the mean first. ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  (One exception would be where there are many observations of the DV at each -or at least many- of the IV-combinations.  In that situation it might be possible to make some assessment of the conditional distribution independent of a model, but it would require a lot of data)

Comment: As far as working with categorical IVs, it's exactly the same as in regression; again this is discussed in a number of posts on site. You may be right about a beta model being a reasonable choice, though that's not strictly GLM; R does have beta regression packages (though if the highest or lowest values in the range are possible, you may want to use 0-1 inflated). An alternative would be not to worry too much about shape and focus on a reasonable model for the mean and the conditional variance via a quasi-model.